# optimizing random mysql row fetch performance

Tags: php, mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have a need to fetch a random row that matches a simple condition from a MySQL table. The table has a Primary Auto-Increment Key, so this is what I'm doing :

```
SELECT v FROM tbl WHERE pkey>$rand_num AND tiny_int_var=0 LIMIT 1
```

The reason I'm doing the `pkey>$rand_num` instead of `pkey=$rand_num` is because my Auto-Increment has holes sometimes. Is there any way to optimize this query or fetching a random line diff+faster?

Comment: What indexes have you defined?  In particular, do you have a composite one defined over `(tiny_int_var, pkey)`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you will get the same row returned anytime $rand_num is the same.

Comment: @eggyal I actually have (pkey, tiny_int_var). In the EXPLAIN I've noticed he's using just the pkey index, although the composite is in the possible_keys. Do you think this will help? how do u decide it's (x, y) and not (y, x) ?

Comment: @eggyal I tried that and it actually made things much worse. btw tiny_var_int is about 80% of the times 0, and 20% 1 if this changes anything.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested against yours for speed, but I think yours will get the same row returned anytime $rand_num is the same.

```
SELECT v
FROM tbl
WHERE tiny_int_var=0
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```